# Why are all my times currenttimeMillis() the same?

Tags: java, time

So I have started using System.currentTimeMillis(); I am trying to test the results between two of my methods. I decided to gut my method so that what it does doesn't get in the way. Basically I am not seeing any change in time. I have something like this:

```
double start= System.currentTimeMillis();
double end=System.currentTimeMillis();

 public void displayMethod()
 {

     System.out.println("The start time is" + start);
     for (ITERATIONS AND STUFF)
     {
        System.out.format(STUFF BEING PRINTED);
    }   
    System.out.println("The end time is" + end);
    double difference = start-end;
    System.out.println("The difference " + difference);
 }
```

The idea is that I have a start time, the time between every print out of the statement and the time at the end. Then it is subtracted to show the difference. However there is no difference and all the times are the same. Why is this happening?

I am considering using nanotime but I don't really know how to use that and I have heard that it takes performance hits.

Can anyone tell me why my times are the same and suggest a way to
fix it or give me an alternative route that is suitable gets the
answer?

Comment: You are setting all of the time variables at the same time (right at the start). If you want them to be different, you need to get the time in different spots in the program's execution.

Comment: The statements are evaluated when they are assigned. Simply using those variables does not cause the expressions to get re-evaluated.

Comment: Oy. You are calling the method three times rapidly in succession and you're surprised that it gives the same answer every time? You need to call it once to collect your start time before you run your method, and call it again after you call your method to collect your end time. How could you possibly expect measuring the end time before you even call your method to work?

Comment: I have it running at the beginning, through the program and at the end. It's still giving me the same time. Even when I remove it from the middle, it still gives me the same number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're capturing all of the times at the beginning with these lines:

```
double thetime= System.currentTimeMillis();
double start= System.currentTimeMillis();
double end=System.currentTimeMillis();
```

You're getting the same times because those lines are executed immediately back to back (and are fast calls so likely happen in less than 1ms)

Adjust your code to:

```
 public void displayMethod()
 {
     long start= System.currentTimeMillis();
     System.out.println("The start time is" + start);
     for (ITERATIONS AND STUFF)
     {
        System.out.format(STUFF BEING PRINTED);
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }   

    long end=System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("The end time is" + end);
    double difference = end-start;
    System.out.println("The difference " + difference);
 }
```

Notice how the declarations of the variables are moved to the places that they are needed. It's important to note that variable assignment happens *at declaration time* not *at usage time*, thus it's important to move the calls to `System.currentTimeMillis()` to the point at which you want to capture the current time.

**Side note:** I adjusted the variables to `long` instead of `double`, as `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns a `long` and there's no reason for a `double` here.

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong. You have to initialize the variable that holds that time at the exact spot you want it shown.

Comment: I thought I understood what was going on.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting all the times at the very beginning. You need to call System.currentTimeMillis() in the place that you want to know the time.

Answer (score 0):

you should call currentTimeMillis minus the start time, where you want to find the total time ran.